# How can I check whether a person is included in a model to make a Job/Post

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have created a School System-like system, that creates a job and sends them to employees/users. I'm almost done making this system however I can't seem to know what do to check if the user is included in the manager model that I created to create a job.

Also, how can a user just see all their job that was assigned to them. All I know is to use `objects.all`but that might only seem to show all of the jobs that was posted, I just want the user to see the job included to them.

Here is my model.py:

```
from django.db import models
from profiles.models import User
# Create your models here.

class Points (models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    points = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class Profile (models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.png',upload_to='profile_pics')


    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username}Profile'


class Manager (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    manager = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Member (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    manager = models.ForeignKey(Manager, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    member = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Job (models.Model):
    manager = models.OneToOneField(Manager, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    member = models.OneToOneField(Member, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, null=False)
    description = models.TextField()
    datePosted = models.DateTimeField (auto_now = True)
    file = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True,upload_to='job_files')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

And Views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView, CreateView
from .models import Job
from profiles.models import User
# Create your views here.

class jobs(ListView):
    model = Job
    template_name = 'users/user_jobs.html'
    context_object_name = 'jobs'


class createjob (CreateView):
    model = Job
    fields = ['member','title', 'description', 'file']
```

How can I proceed?

Answer (score 2):

Use `get_queryset` to filter job by user

**Ex:**

```
class jobs(ListView):
    model = Job
    template_name = 'users/user_jobs.html'
    context_object_name = 'jobs'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Job.objects.filter(member__member=self.request.user)
```